# Android in QEMU

Tags: android, linux, emulation, qemu, fastboot

Is there a way to emulate full Android system with fastboot, recovery and etc. in QEMU arm64 mode?

I found how to install Android x86 in QEMU but no information about normal version. I need normal full Android with bootloader.

Comment: Not clear if you are aware of https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/cuttlefish

Comment: Isn't the Android emulator from Android SDK based on Qemu ?

Comment: Will it emulate fastboot?